# How to Export user libraries with project files to be able to compile the project on another pc

Tags: java

In few days i have an exam of java, we will have to make a program based on the given problem.
we can use any file/Library/package ... what ever we want.

So while i was writing my programs i ran in to a problem while writing the tests with junit5, i wanted to used the Hamcrest library to make life little bit easier since we are going to have max 5 hours for the exam. 
But i found out that the default library of JUnit5 that Eclipse includes automatically, contains an outdated/incomplete version of Hamcrest library.

So tried to include also the new version(2.1), but there was the conflict in the libraries, then to solve this i removed the default library of JUnit5 and
created two user libraries:
1. Hamcrest
2. Junit5

and started using them, no problem there.

But the problem is that during the exam we have to upload a zip file to the university's server that contains everything to be able to compile the project. i tried exporting the project in all possible combinations as zip, tar, jar but i'm not able to export the userlibraries.

Comment: Do you use Maven?

Comment: No, just Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
             Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
             Build id: 20190614-1200

Comment: You should use Maven unless you have to use only Eclipse without any build tool. Use Maven *and* Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is the exam requirements it has to be only Eclipse, probably there is some automated process that tries to complile the code ecc

Comment: Then change your code to use only the included libraries. Even an old version of Hamcrest should give you all the assertions you need. Don't waste time on this.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys i will try to adapt the code for default library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a ZIP-File from your project-Folder (including .settings, .project, .classpath etc.)... Just make sure your libraries are located inside your project-folder and the references are relative from the basepath and not an absolute path (check the .classpath-File if you're not sure).

But also depending on the default JUnit-Lib seems like a good idea. Don't make your life harder as it needs to be!

Comment: You are a life saver ahaha, your idea worked, i just included/linked the folder containg Hamcrest library files(Hamcrset-javadoc-2.1.jar, Hamcrset-source-2.1.jar and Hamcrset-2.1.jar). then in the BuildPath\Libraries i included the Hamcrset-2.1.jar file from the workspace. it worked

Comment: now i have another little problem not that important, in the process that i described in upper comment when i include the Hamcrset-2.1.jar i doesn't link automatically Hamcrset-javadoc-2.1.jar, Hamcrset-source-2.1.jar files, i have ti do it manually even if they are in the same folder.

Comment: You always have to add javadoc and sources manually. There is no magic that adds them for you ;) Check your .classpath file, you will have an entry like this: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom.jar" sourcepath="doc/jdom-1.0.zip"/>

Comment: Okay thanks again, i asked for that because while i was creating the userlibrary with same jar files it was automatically picking the location for source and javadoc jar files